# Standard library - higher-precision floating point?

Tags: python, floating-point

So, I'm having some precision issues in Python.

I would like to calculate functions like this:

```
P(x,y) = exp(-x)/(exp(-x) + exp(-y))
```

Where x and y might be >1000.  Python's  math.exp(-1000) (in 2.6 at least!) doesn't have enough floating point precision to handle this.

1. this form looks like logistic / logit / log-odds, but it's not, right?  Is there some algebraic simplification I'm missing here?
2. I know about Decimal, but am not sure if it applies here
3. looks like homework, but it's not, I promise!

(Also, I'm open to titles!  I couldn't think of a good one for this question!)

Comment: "I know about Decimal but am unsure if it applies here"? After you TRIED it, of what are you unsure?

Comment: Well, for one, as I pointed out below, I didn't realize that Decimal() had a exp method.  Doing math.exp(Decimal()) doesn't work.  If you want to give me the RTFM treatment, then at least link to TFM.

Comment: Of course math.exp() wouldn't work; it expects a float. The math module mirrors the C math functions. I don't want to give you the RTFM treatment, I want to give you the "type exp into the index panel on the CHM docs and it lists TWO decimal methods followed by the cmath and math functions (or use the not so flash `http://docs.python.org/search.html?q=exp` (decimal exp methods are 7th and 8th hits))" treatment and the "avoid vague waffle like 'I know about X but am not sure if it applies here'" treatment.

Comment: Fwiw, that documentation is different between 2.5 and 2.6, so good on python-doc maintainers.  I didn't think the exp part would be relevant in my internal model, honestly, and it pleasantly surprises me that Decimal() has its own math functions as methods, but it's not expected, considering it's at odds with cmath.  I was expecting the idiom something more like exp(SpecialType()), not SpecialType().exp.  I'm glad to be educated on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could divide the top and bottom by `exp(-x)`

```
P(x,y) = 1/(1 + exp(x-y))
```

Comment: or, with less wear and tear on the poor old brain cells, multiply the top and bottom by `exp(x)` :-)

Comment: While true, this does not solve the problem, because exp(x-y) can still have a value of (x-y) > 1000.

Comment: +1 better to use brain than muscle. @steveha: x and y are likely to be similar in order, and this would then greatly improve the situation.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something i was missing here.  Jeepers, I feel like a moron! I tried to take the log of all of it, which obviously fails.

Comment: @steveha: this solves the problem, because even in the cases of `exp(x-y)` being too big or too small it still produces the correct answer. If `x-y` is very negative, `exp(x-y)` will be too small and will evaluate to 0, and the whole expression evaluates to 1, which is correct (to the the degree representible by floats anyway). If `x-y` is very positive, `exp(x-y)` will be too big and will evaluate to infinity, and the whole expression evaluates to 0, which is also correct (to the the degree representible by floats).

Comment: @newacct: "exp(x-y) will be too big and will evaluate to infinity": true in algebra, not necessarily so in a computer language; on Windows Python 2.6. math.exp(1000) gives `OverflowError: math range error` ... you still need to do something like `delta = x - y; result = 0.0 if delta >= TOOBIG else 1/(1+math.exp(delta))` or use try/except.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(-1000).exp()
Decimal('5.075958897549456765291809480E-435')
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 60
>>> decimal.Decimal(-1000).exp()
Decimal('5.07595889754945676529180947957433691930559928289283736183239E-435')
```

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating how to actually use Decimal here.  I didn't realize it had a 'exp' method.

Answer (score 4):

```
P(x,y) = exp(-x)/(exp(-x) + exp(-y))
```

is equivalent to:

```
P(x,y) = 1 / (1 + exp(x-y))
```

Perhaps the second one works without the use of more precision.

Comment: I would accept yours as well.  I don't know why I just couldn't see it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/) package for arbitrary precision floating-point reliable arithmetic.

Comment: Good to know, but not part of standard library.  Thanks for linking though!

Comment: And a pain to install sometimes, especially under Windows.